# Why was this accepted answer deleted: Attitude should be professional

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts

@matt-e-Эллен

["Attitude should be professional looks need not to be" is it grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322050/attitude-should-be-professional-looks-need-not-to-be-is-it-grammatically-corre)

It looks like the accepted answer to the above question was deleted --I'm not sure why.  I didn't think it was a particularly good answer, but it doesn't seem to be an exact duplicate of any other answer, and it's the one the OP marked as accepted.

Comment: While I'm not necessarily disputing that it was the accepted answer, I can't see any evidence *now* that it was accepted -- even in the mod timeline which is supposed to record all significant and not-so-significant events. There was a VLQ flag raised on that answer.

Comment: The reason I know it was accepted was that my answer was initially the accepted one, and then the OP switched to that one --presumably because they wanted the most minimal acceptable change to their original sentence.   While it's far from a great answer, I think calling it VLQ is a bit much, it does answer the question, apparently in the way the OP found most helpful.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Just FYI, it's in the mod timeline on the answer (but not on the question).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realise it was the accepted answer. It's not something I usually check for.

In the mod queue posts are presented without votes or formatting.

It is a very bad answer. It gives the minor correction to the sentence without explanation. If you're not looking carefully you could be forgiven for thinking they hadn't even corrected the sentence.

Sometimes I give people the benefit of the doubt and ask them to justify their answer, but this time I didn't.

I will be more careful in future.

Comment: Well, seeing —  and I waited a bit to see if someone else would point this out,— as a mistake in good faith was made, and the answer was accepted by the OP himself, shouldn't the answer be undeleted?

Comment: The answer is *poorly* presented and without support, but it is certainly not wrong. *It is a very bad answer* suggests it was ungrammatical, or just contained a link, or  was off-topic, it was neither of the two. The correction is indeed minor, but it is an appropriate one.  Why do we have downvotes for, if not to say when an answer is "bad"?

Comment: For me a very bad answer is one that has no effort put into it, i.e. just the word with no explanation.

Comment: Fine, I'm not defending the quality of that answer. But the point being made is that it was accepted by the OP, the user who asked the question, and for him that answer was the most helpful of the bunch.

Comment: Let me understand this. So I know for future. The best thing I can do for the site is not delete rubbish because it's an accepted answer? I've undeleted it, but I question the utility of letting someone believe they've been helped when they haven't.